# usb to serial signals

Tags: usb

I have a stock ftdi usb to serial converter. If i plug it, then on tx connector I always have a 1, 5V, even if I don't do anything. And if sending 0's there my led just gets about 0.5 of default brightness. Should it be this way? I thought default level should be 0. Thank you.

Comment: Did you study the asynchronous serial protocol (with TTL level voltages, not rs232 levels)? That might be more relevant than your thoughts....

Comment: "I thought default level should be 0." Based on what?

Comment: How "your LED" is supposed to receive serial signals?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I studied these things. So there is no way to have 0V by sending something to tx? I mean without using inverter. led is just for indication.

Comment: Read the FTDIchip.com datasheet for FT232, there is a "bitbang mode" that supports setting levels on each of the 8 I/O pins. This requires using the D2XX native driver API commands, which are documented in the programmers' guide.

Answer (score 1):

> If i plug it, then on tx connector I always have a 1, 5V, even if I don't do anything.

No surprise here, UART has its "idle" state HIGH. So TX is expected to stay at VCCIO when there is no data transfer.

> And if sending 0's there my led just gets about 0.5 of default brightness. Should it be this way?

No idea how you connected the LED - and how much current your FTDI chip can drive - but there is always the stop bit to consider. The stop bit is HIGH, too.